# How to Subtract rows after group by in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I had a `dataframe` and after applying `groupby().sum`, I got this outcome.

**What I have**

```
Market     Type      Amount                                   
A          Buy        46.56
B          Buy       100.00
           Sell      100.00
C          Buy       697.20
D          Buy       100.00 <--
           Sell       40.00 <--
...        ...        ...
```

**What I want now**

```
Market     Type      Amount                                   
A          Buy        46.56
C          Buy       697.20
D          Buy        60.00 <--
...        ...         ...
```

**Things to consider**

- `B` should remove from the `dataframe` because `100.00 - 100.00 = 0`
- Always `Buy Amount > Sell Amount`

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is not optimized way, but you can try this code block;

```
idx = df[df["Type"] == 'Sell'].index
df.loc[idx, 'Amount'] = df.loc[idx, 'Amount'] * (-1) 

df = df.groupby(['Market'], as_index=False).agg({'Type': 'min', 'Amount': 'sum'})
df = df.loc[~((df['Amount'] == 0))]
```

Comment: Code is fine but it gave me the sum of Amount.

Comment: it returns substraction of amount(buy) - amount(sell) with groupbying Market. I guess it is what you claimed in the question. I made assumptions buy amount is always higher than sell amount as you claimed.

Comment: I need `buy - sell`

Comment: I took -1 times of sell amounts before the groupby operation. This means (buy + (- sell)) so it is same thing with buy-sell :)

Comment: In output, I got `B   200.00` But it should be `B   0.0` or remove that row

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer with changing 'sell' to 'Sell' at the first line of code block. I guess, it was the problem for your dataframe

Comment: I have added `as_index=False` to your answer to stabilize the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the df rows:

```
import pandas as pd
new_data = []
data = [['A', 'Buy', 46.56], ['B', 'Buy', 100.00], ['','Sell', 100],
        ['C', 'Buy', 697.20], ['D', 'Buy', 100.00], ['','Sell', 40]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Market','Type','Amount'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Type'] == 'Buy' and df.iloc[index+1]['Type'] == 'Buy':
        new_data.append([row['Market'], row['Type'],row['Amount']])
    elif row['Type'] == 'Buy' and df.iloc[index + 1]['Type'] == 'Sell':
        if df.iloc[index]['Amount'] - df.iloc[index+1]['Amount']:
            new_data.append([row['Market'], row['Type'],
                             df.iloc[index]['Amount'] - df.iloc[index+1]['Amount']])

print(pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['Market','Type','Amount']))
```

Outputs:

```
  Market Type  Amount
0      A  Buy   46.56
1      C  Buy  697.20
2      D  Buy   60.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to to it that I think is more "pythonic" : use a [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

First reset your index, then apply pivot on 'Type' column, and you get your Buy/Sell amounts in columns, then you can just substract them :

```py
df = df.pivot(index='Market', columns='Type')
```

```
        Amount       
Type       Buy   Sell
Market               
A        45.65    NaN
B       100.00  100.0
C       697.20    NaN
D       100.00   40.0
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df['Amount']['Buy'] - df['Amount']['Sell'].fillna(0), columns=['Buy'])
```

(Use `fillna(0)` to make sure you substract 0 when NA)

You can then filter out 0 values

```py
df = df[df['Buy'] > 0 ]
```

which will get you :

```
           Buy
Market        
A        45.65
C       697.20
D        60.00
```